# I'm generating a pdf with laravel-dompdf and I am using server path to show images in the pdf. Is it secure?

Tags: laravel, security, pdf, laravel-5.5, dompdf

I am using laravel-dompdf to generate a pdf but to show images in that pdf I tried the route and controller approach but it's working for webpage but not for pdf. That's I am using the server path (**/home/shashank/work/jobs/storage/app/{{$photo}}**).

I want to know if it's safe or not.

Comment: You can restrict filesystem access through your webserver and set read only permissions within the allowed directories. So long as you're not storing sensitive information I don't see why you would have trouble with this approach. Is there a reason why you're not storing the images in the public directory though?

Comment: Thanks. The pdf will have a user's photo which is not supposed to be public according to the requirements.

Comment: @btl but if change the permissions of the folder to read only then how will I store the uploaded files in it.